# JSON парсинг, ошибка Unresolved reference

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin

Делаю по видео уроку. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vcn4OuV4Ixg
Напоролся на ошибку, не могу исправить никак. Помогите.

Unresolved reference: data. (fetchData.kt)

> MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.sfp.parsejson

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var click:Button
    lateinit var data:TextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        click = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        data = findViewById(R.id.fetchedata) as TextView

        click.setOnClickListener(object:View.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(view:View) {
                val process = fetchData()
                process.execute()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> fetchData.kt

```
package com.example.sfp.parsejson

import android.os.AsyncTask

import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import java.net.URL

class fetchData : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    var data: String = ""
    private var dataParsed = ""
    private var singleParsed = ""
    override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): Void? {
        try {
            val url = URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/b1kxl")

            val httpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            val inputStream = httpURLConnection.inputStream
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            var line: String? = ""
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine()
                data += line!!
            }

            val JA = JSONArray(data)
            for (i in 0 until JA.length()) {
                val JO = JA.get(i) as JSONObject
                singleParsed = "Name:" + JO.get("name") + "\n" +
                        "Password:" + JO.get("password") + "\n" +
                        "Contact:" + JO.get("contact") + "\n" +
                        "Country:" + JO.get("country") + "\n"

                dataParsed += singleParsed
            }
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }


    override fun onPostExecute(aVoid: Void) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid)
        MainActivity.data.setText(this.dataParsed)
    }
}
```

> activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sfp.parsejson.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="click me"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/button">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:hint="Fetched Text Here!"
            android:id="@+id/fetchedata"/>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> JSON https://api.myjson.com/bins/b1kxl

```
[{"name":"Ivan","password":"try","contact":"russia@mail.ru","country":"Russia"},{"name":"Layo Choo","password":"122223qweer","contact":"china@mail.ch","country":"China"},{"name":"Johan","password":"333qweer","contact":"deutsch@mail.de","country":"Germany"}]
```

И вот такая ошибка при использовании типа TextView.

```
09-11 14:43:26.136 3804-5815/com.example.sfp.parsejson E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                         Process: com.example.sfp.parsejson, PID: 3804
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                          Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                                             at com.example.sfp.parsejson.fetchData.doInBackground(fetchData.kt:32)
                                                                             at com.example.sfp.parsejson.fetchData.doInBackground(fetchData.kt:18)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

---

```
package com.example.sfp.parsejson

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView

import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import java.net.URL

class fetchData : AsyncTask<Void, Void, TextView>() {
    var data: String = ""
    private var dataParsed = ""
    private var singleParsed = ""
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): TextView? {
        try {
            val url = URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/b1kxl")

            val httpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            val inputStream = httpURLConnection.inputStream
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            var line: String? = ""
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine()
                data += line!!
            }

            val JA = JSONArray(data)
            for (i in 0 until JA.length()) {
                val JO = JA.get(i) as JSONObject
                singleParsed = "Name:" + JO.get("name") + "\n" +
                        "Password:" + JO.get("password") + "\n" +
                        "Contact:" + JO.get("contact") + "\n" +
                        "Country:" + JO.get("country") + "\n"

                dataParsed += singleParsed
            }
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }


    override fun onPostExecute(aVoid: TextView) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid)
        aVoid.text = this.dataParsed
    }
}
```

Comment: А что за ошибка? Добавили бы стек трассы

Comment: Error:(56, 22) Unresolved reference: data;
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

Comment: это тексто ошибки, а не стек трассы, в стеке описаны все вызовы функций вплоть до последней, в которой ошибка произошла, по стеку можно понять где именно была проблема. А так, предположительно проблема в `MainActivity.data.setText(this.dataParsed)`

Comment: Как сформировать стек в Android Studio?

Comment: можно сказать что я придираюсь, но за заголовок просто жирный минус. Он должен быть говорящим, а не выкриком размягшего мозгом

Comment: Добавил вариант с типом TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var click:Button
lateinit var data:TextView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    click = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
    data = findViewById(R.id.fetchedata) as TextView

    click.setOnClickListener(object:View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(view:View) {
            fetchData(data).execute()
        }
    })
  }
}
```

> fetchData.kt

```
class fetchData(val textView: TextView) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
var data: String = ""
private var dataParsed = ""
private var singleParsed = ""
override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): String? {

    try {
        val url = URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/b1kxl")

        val httpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        val inputStream = httpURLConnection.inputStream
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

        for (line in bufferedReader.readLine()){
            data+=line;
        }

        val JA = JSONArray(data)
        for (i in 0 until JA.length()) {
            val JO = JA.get(i) as JSONObject
            singleParsed = "Name:" + JO.get("name") + "\n" +
                    "Password:" + JO.get("password") + "\n" +
                    "Contact:" + JO.get("contact") + "\n" +
                    "Country:" + JO.get("country") + "\n"

            dataParsed += singleParsed
        }
    } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return dataParsed
}


override fun onPostExecute(aVoid: String) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid)
    textView.text = aVoid
    }
}
```

Comment: Крашится приложение с ошибкой.
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1;Process: com.example.sfp.parsejson, PID: 11593;java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Comment: @userBuzzer, то что Вы написали нам ни о чём не говорит, самое интересное в стектрейсе начинается обычно со слов "Caused by", а лучше полный стек ошибки и научиться самому понимать что там написано и в какое место кода он указывает.

Comment: @userBuzzer обновил ответ